# Warden not available in rspec tests when using Grape as a Rack application

Tags: rspec2, warden

I am having a problem getting the Warden's hash to appear in the request hash in my RSpec tests. When I run my application in development mode the Warden keys are there, but in the test environment everything is nil. I have included my basic rspec config below. If anyone has any ideas where I am going wrong I'd really like to know, I've been fiddling with this for almost a full-day.

When running in development mode Warden is found, but when running in test mode `env['warden']` is always `nil`

Here is an example of what I get when I inpsect the warden hash inside request object during development mode:

```
request['warden']
=> Warden::Proxy:70272688271480 @config={:default_scope=>:default, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:_all=>[:password, :basic]}, :intercept_401=>true, :failure_app=>GrapeApe::BadAuthentication}
```

Here is what I get when I inspect the warden hash inside the request object during tests:

```
request['warden']
=> nil
```

Spec Helper File

```
require 'rubygems'

ENV["RACK_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require 'rack/test'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'factory_girl'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

FactoryGirl.find_definitions

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.expect_with :rspec
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  config.after :each do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.app = GrapeApe::App.new
  config.server_port = 9293
end
```

Example Spec where warden should throw a 403 response because the user has not been authenticated.

```
it "should get a specfic sketch" do
  get "/api/v1/sketches/#{@sketch.id}"
  JSON.parse(last_response.body)['files'].should == ["foo"]
end
```

Example Error:

```
Failure/Error: JSON.parse(last_response.body)['files'].should == ["foo"]
JSON::ParserError:
756: unexpected token at 'undefined method `authenticated?' for nil:NilClass'
```

Relevant Grape helper methods where the warden keys are inspected

```
module GrapeApe
  module Helpers
    def warden
      env['warden']
    end

    def authenticated
      if warden.authenticated?
        return true
      elsif params[:access_token] and
        User.find_for_token_authentication("access_token" => params[:access_token])
        return true
      else
        error!('401 Unauthorized', 401)
      end
    end

    def current_user
        warden.user || User.find_for_token_authentication("access_token" => params[:access_token])
    end

    def authenticated_user
      authenticated
      error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless current_user
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: I'm having same problem. Did you manage to solve the issue?